# Dry up two constants in one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, constants, dry

Is there a way to dry up this two constance? Only the wording bill and ship is different, is it possible to change it with an parameter, so at the end, i have only one constance?

```
BILLING_ADDRESS_MAPPING = {
  first_name:   :bill_first_name_c,
  last_name:    :bill_last_name_c
}

SHIPPING_ADDRESS_MAPPING = {
  first_name:   :ship_first_name_c,
  last_name:    :ship_last_name_c
}
```

Each of them will be used later in something like this:

```
  ship_address = Address.new

  SHIPPING_ADDRESS_MAPPING.each do |rails_attr, sugar_attr|
    ship_address.send(:"#{ rails_attr }=", sugar_opportunity.send(sugar_attr))
  end

  ship_address.save
```

Comment: What's `sugar_opportunity`?

Comment: It's a hash from a parameter.

Comment: You could reduce those constants further at the expense of clarity, which defeats the purpose.

Comment: Can you post `sugar_opportunity` too?

Comment: @Substantial: Thank you for clarity. but maybe in a small code its not that important :)
@ Surya: sugar_opportunity contains a record entry from the sugarcrm (rest api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constants in ruby are not allowed to change change dynamically. But if you keep address_mapping not as a constant, then there definitely a work around:

```
def address_mapping(type)
address_mapping = {
  first_name:   "#{type}_first_name_c".to_sym,
  last_name:    "#{type}_last_name_c".to_sym
}
return address_mapping
end
```

This is your method, in which you would be passing "billing" or "shipping" as strings and the result should be as you wanted.

Now you should be using it something like:

```
ship_address = Address.new
address_mapping("shipping").each do |rails_attr, sugar_attr|
  ship_address.send(:"#{ rails_attr }=", sugar_opportunity.send(sugar_attr))
end
ship_address.save
```

Let me know if I have understood it wrong. Hope it helps :)

Comment: You understood me pretty well. I have now an `NoMethodError:undefined method address_mapping`, i guess i should rewrite the `address_mapping("shipping").each do |rails_attr, sugar_attr|
  ship_address.send(:"#{ rails_attr }=", sugar_opportunity.send(sugar_attr))
end`. I will work on it thx you.